# child div can not grow when parent' position is relative inside an absolute

Tags: html, css

I have some nested div which I am showing some data to users, the problem is, parent width does not grow according to child's width.

below are the HTML and CSS I have :

```css
#drppanel {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0px;
  width: 141.078px;
  min-width: 141.078px;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto !important;
}

#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-height: 240px;
  width: auto !important;
}

#child1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto !impoetant;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="drppanel">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

if you run below code, the content does not shown completely because the parent's width does not grow according to it's content.

I mean it show show like below :

[image]

Comment: Remove overflow-y from parent.

Comment: I need Vertical scroll, if I remove that, I just see three p tags.

Comment: Remove overflow completely from parent.

Comment: I don't want to remove Vertial scroll. it must be there.

Comment: If you want the `width` to grow, why did you set both `width` and `min-width` to the same value (of `141.078px`)?

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of the **#child1** element and set it to fit-content, that way it'll take the full width of the content, also you had a typo of the word important.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#drppanel {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0px;
  width: 141.078px;
  min-width: 141.078px;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto !important;
}
#parent {
  overflow: hidden auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 240px;
  width: auto !important;
}
#child1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto !important;
  height: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="drppanel">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>
      <p>
        Lonng text here is set to show Long text
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please marque the answer if it solved your problem